# Remove leap year day from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
datetime
2012-01-01    125.5010
2012-01-02    125.5010
2012-01-03    125.5010
2012-02-04    125.5010
2012-02-05    125.5010
2012-02-29    125.5010
2012-02-28    125.5010
2016-01-07    125.5010
2016-01-08    125.5010
2016-02-29     81.6237
```

I would like to drop all rows corresponding to Feb 29th, resulting in foll. data frame:

```
datetime
2012-01-01    125.5010
2012-01-02    125.5010
2012-01-03    125.5010
2012-02-04    125.5010
2012-02-05    125.5010
2012-02-28    125.5010
2016-01-07    125.5010
2016-01-08    125.5010
```

Right now, I am just doing it manually:

`df.drop(df.index[['2012-02-29']])`. How can I make it so that it works for all years, without haveing to manually specify row index.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997007/pandas-dataframe-delete-specific-date-in-all-leap-years

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mask it and remove [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(df.index.month != 2) | (df.index.day != 29)]
```

Solution with function:

```
def is_leap_and_29Feb(s):
    return (s.index.month != 2) | (s.index.day != 29)

mask = is_leap_and_29Feb(df)
print mask
#[False False False False False  True False False False  True]

print df.loc[~mask]
#            datetime
#2012-01-01   125.501
#2012-01-02   125.501
#2012-01-03   125.501
#2012-02-04   125.501
#2012-02-05   125.501
#2012-02-28   125.501
#2016-01-07   125.501
#2016-01-08   125.501
```

Or:

(s.index.month != 2) | (s.index.day != 29)

Comment: That's a pity you edited your original answer, it had more general applicability.

Comment: No problem, rollback is super. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

If your dataframe has already the `datetime` column as index you can:

```
df = df[~((df.index.month == 2) & (df.index.day == 29))]
```

this should remove the rows containing the day February 29th for all years.

Comment: slight variation of this if the date is not an index 

`df = df[~((df['Date'].dt.month == 2) &(df['Date'].dt.day ==29))]`

Answer (score 7):

You can see the date as `string` and see if it ends with `02-29`:

```
df = df[~df.index.str.endswith('02-29')]
```

Using this method, you can use any string-comparism method like `contains`, etc.