# Exclude leap year days from date_range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I generate a series of dates like this:

```
pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2012-12-31")
```

How can I automatically exclude the leap year dates? Feb 29th in the years where they occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From version [`0.19.0`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13727) you can use [`DatetimeIndex.is_leap_year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.is_leap_year.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2012-12-31")
print (rng)
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04',
               '2001-01-05', '2001-01-06', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-08',
               '2001-01-09', '2001-01-10',
               ...
               '2012-12-22', '2012-12-23', '2012-12-24', '2012-12-25',
               '2012-12-26', '2012-12-27', '2012-12-28', '2012-12-29',
               '2012-12-30', '2012-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=4383, freq='D')

print (rng.is_leap_year)
[False False False ...,  True  True  True]

print (rng[~rng.is_leap_year])
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04',
               '2001-01-05', '2001-01-06', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-08',
               '2001-01-09', '2001-01-10',
               ...
               '2011-12-22', '2011-12-23', '2011-12-24', '2011-12-25',
               '2011-12-26', '2011-12-27', '2011-12-28', '2011-12-29',
               '2011-12-30', '2011-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=3285, freq=None)
```

Comment: This does not answer [user308827](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308827/user308827)'s original question. This code omits entire leap years, where user308827 wanted only to omit leap *days*.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966422/remove-leap-year-day-from-pandas-dataframe) is a link to a solution of the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`.date_range()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) doesn't take a parameter allowing user to exclude leap dates from the list. However, you can exclude them yourself and create a new [DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) object with the non-leap year dates:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from calendar import isleap

>>> dates = pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2012-12-31")
>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(data=(t for t in dates if not isleap(t.year)), freq="D")
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04',
           '2001-01-05', '2001-01-06', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-08',
           '2001-01-09', '2001-01-10',
           ...
           '2011-12-22', '2011-12-23', '2011-12-24', '2011-12-25',
           '2011-12-26', '2011-12-27', '2011-12-28', '2011-12-29',
           '2011-12-30', '2011-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=3285, freq='D')
```